# Diffing tools for Mac OSX

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, svn, diff

Are there tools for diffing without subversion?

Right now I am just writing code on my local but the ability to diff versions would be nice...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for GUI-based tools, I've been a fan of [Kaleidoscope](http://www.kaleidoscopeapp.com/) for a while now. It is non-free, but has a demo.

The Mac version of [SourceGear's DiffMerge](http://sourcegear.com/diffmerge/) *is* free. I've never used the Mac version, but the Windows version is pretty decent. And of course if you install Xcode, you should get FileMerge from Apple, which works in a pinch (although I guess these days it's not technically free as it costs $5 to get Xcode from the Mac App Store, or registration as a Mac or iOS developer for $99/year; I don't know if you can acquire FileMerge individually for free).

Answer (score 2):

If you install [Apple Developer Tools](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Developer_Tools) on your Mac (available on the Snow Leopard install CD as part of Xcode), you also have a program called '[FileMerge](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20030217061153119)' (`/Developer/Applications/Utilities/FileMerge.app`) which is quite a nice graphical comparison program.

Of course as mentioned above, you can also use Macports or Fink to install regular *nix diff tools.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe take a look at [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/). You could at least install diff through that. There are probably more direct solutions, but MacPorts is pretty awesome.

Answer (score 1):

My favorite diff tool is [Araxis Merge](http://www.araxis.com/merge-overview.html) which is also cross platform (Macintosh, Windows). It might seem pricy, but I run it before every commit.

Answer (score 0):

I like [xxdiff](http://furius.ca/xxdiff/) which has a MacOS port, though I've never used it on a Mac.